# Attribute-based encryption for cloud storage

Tags: terminology, abe, secure-storage

I'm trying to understand attribute-based encryption schemes. Almost all articles describe that they are designed for cloud storage, but as I understand, almost all computing (encryption & decryption) is performed client-side and not in the cloud.

In this regard, I have a question: How are these schemes related to cloud storage?

Comment: ABE scheme gives control over who can decrypt the ciphertext in the cloud (or any untrusted server) based on access policy (refer to KP-ABE , CP-ABE). Give us a reference of cloud storage  to help you much better

Comment: Andrey, please [edit] your question to include references what kind of systems, you're talking about including a description in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is related to Cloud storage in the sense that you don't have to trust the server you put your data on. 
Usually, the access control is done via authentication. This requires the server to be trusted. 
However in the case of Cloud storage, you don't know anything about the server hosting the data, so being able to do access control with the encryption scheme is great.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, many cloud storage systems are using ABE (Attribute Based Encryption) schemes. In this system they can encrypt data on the client side, using an “access structure” rather than “in the cloud” because the cloud is a third party server, so we do not trust it. That's why they are using the client side.

Also, ABE is well suited for cloud scenarios because we can share data based on different attributes.